# How to take input from the user on which product to track?

Tags: user-behavior, mobile-application

I'm working on an app which tracks a product from online shopping sites like Amazon and notifies you when there is a price drop.

**But the problem is - how to take input from the user on which product to track?**

i.e. How should the user let the app know which product to track?

Copying the URL of product, and pasting it in my app, would help. But this is not user friendly.

What are more user friendly ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was gonna suggest the extension route but if that doesn't work then you can provide a simple search bar in your app that can use Amazon API to get the search results. That way the user doesn't have to do double search or do copy pasting of urls.
If this a iPhone app, you can create a share extension that will allow user to send the item to your app. I am positive that Android has the same.

Comment: Great idea @sai I checked out docs and we can list the app in shareable in Android too. Search option looks good too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

Have you ever considered making a browser extension.

They're pretty awesome. In chrome for example you could have an icon in the top right. Or when the user right clicks.

Also pasting the URL I don't think is that unfriendly. Most people know how to do it. And if you include a how to on your site it should be okay.

I would recommend doing both

Comment: Thanks @Carl Saldanha for your answer. That option was across my mind. I made a chrome extension some time back. But, that requires my user to install both my app and extension and I should build the extension for various browsers. I'm looking for other alternatives. Great input by the way, Carl.Thanks.